# How to export database structure from Firebird?

Tags: database-design, export, firebird

I'm doing replication and I need to export db structure from one Firebird db (dialect 3) into another. I've seen a couple tools like IBPump and FBExport, however all I can find is how to export all the data and not the structure. Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to do this:

1. A metadata-only backup using gbak:

   ```
   gbak -backup -meta_data employee employee.meta.fbk
   ```

   And then restore that backup.
2. A metadata-only restore using gbak:

   ```
   gbak -create employee.fbk mytest.fdb -meta_data
   ```

   This can be useful if you already have a backup with data.
3. Exporting the DDL of a database with ISQL (or another tool)

   ```
   isql -ex -o ddldump.sql /path/to/your/database.fdb
   ```

   And then use that script to populate a new database.

For options 1 & 2 see [gbak: Backup & Restore Recipes: Meta Data Only](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/gbak/firebird-gbak.html#gbak-recipies-metadata)
For option 3 see [ISQL: Command Line Switches](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/isql/firebird-isql.html#isql-switches).